# Xamarin.ios application crashes with signal SIGSEGV

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ibm-mobilefirst, ios-simulator

so i am testing MobileFirst sample using xamarin.forms in visual studio 2017,
and IPhone simulator: iPhone 7 Plus iOS 10.3 (using virtual machine)

this is the code:

```
 public async void ObtainToken()
    {
        try
        {

             WorklightClient = App.WorklightClient;
            WorklightAccessToken accessToken = await WorklightClient.AuthorizationManager.ObtainAccessToken("");

            if (accessToken.Value != null && accessToken.Value != "")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received the following access token value: " + accessToken.Value);
                 await DisplayAlert("Token Value", accessToken.Value, "OK");

                StringBuilder uriBuilder = new StringBuilder().Append("/adapters/javaAdapter/resource/greet");

                WorklightResourceRequest request = WorklightClient.ResourceRequest(new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString(), UriKind.Relative), "GET");
                request.SetQueryParameter("name", "world!");
                WorklightResponse response = await request.Send();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success: " + response.ResponseText);
                DisplayAlert("Greeting Get Request", response.ResponseText.ToString(), "OK");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
        }
    }
```

is craches before accessing to the first line (in debug) 
i am not sure if it is xamarin error or instantiation worklighclient
the error :

```
2017-07-03 12:41:02.461 XamarinMFPTest.iOS[4642:52640] Will try to create a instance if null
2017-07-03 12:53:52.310 XamarinMFPTest.iOS[4642:52640] [FATAL] [WORKLIGHT] App Crash: Crashed with signal SIGSEGV (code SEGV_MAPERR)
```

ps: this code is running for android and uwp

Comment: Have you enabled key chain sharing in your app ?

Comment: in visual studio? there is no capabilitie for chain sharing

Comment: i found somewhere with google this explanation of the signal : SIGSEGV Access to an invalid memory address. The address exist, but your program does not have access to it.